# Vertical scrolling in python attracts error (using grid method)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
self.entryVariable3 = tkinter.StringVar()
self.entry3 = tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable3)     

self.entry3.grid(row=16,columnspan=2,rowspan=3,sticky="EW",pady=15)
self.entryVariable3.set("WELCOME!")

scroll2 = tkinter.Scrollbar(self)       
self.entry3.config(yscrollcommand=scroll2.set)
scroll2.config(command=self.entry3.yview)
scroll2.grid(row=17,column=2,sticky='W')

self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=2)
self.resizable(True,False) 
self.update()
self.geometry(self.geometry())
```

_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-yscrollcommand"

only the x-scroll is working but not the yscroll (python 3.4) !**

Comment: Can you please provide information, and what you tried?

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will allow us to assist you with you question.

Comment: From your code it looks like you are importing tkinter 2 times. probably `import tkinter` and `import tkinter as tk`. Do not double import. There is no need. Just stick with `import tkinter as tk` as its the arguably the most common import practice and probably the better choice.

Comment: An Entry widget only accepts a single line of text so it doesn't make sense to give it a vertical scrollbar. [The Scrollbar widget docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scrollbar.htm) specifically say: "Horizontal scrollbars can also be used with the Entry widget". If Entry widgets could also use a vertical scrollbar the docs would mention it.

Answer (score 1):

You problem I believe is you are trying to use the argument `yscrollcommand` on an Entry widget. Entry widgets do not have multiple rows so there is no way you can yscroll an Entry filed.

To use yscroll you will need to use it on a canvas, text box or a list box. There might be more widgets that can use yscroll scrollbars but Entry is not one of them.

Comment: But how can I change variable values in text widget as I do with Entry widget? btw thanks for providing a reason for my problem.

Comment: @BishalBanerjee Why is it you want to use a scroll bar in the first place? If I knew the reason for what you were doing with the entry box I could probably provide a solution.